# Angular4 getting query string with multiple parameters

Tags: angular, routes

I have just run into a very strange issue.
I have this bit of code:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    // Only update the elq if it changes (remember: changing a parameter causes the page to refresh)
    var elq = params['elqid'];
    console.log(params);
    console.log(elq);
    if (elq) {
      this._resultsService.elq = elq;
    }
  });
}
```

and if I do this:

> http://localhost:4200/steps/one?elqid=RStesting123

I do indeed get 2 console log outputs:

```
{
    elqid: "RSTesting123"
}
```

And if I do this:

> http://localhost:4200/steps/one?cid=em-elq-33781&elqid=RStesting123

It also works fine.
But, If I do this (instead of `&` I am using `&amp;`):

> http://localhost:4200/steps/one?cid=em-elq-33781&elqid=RStesting123

I get this output:

```
{
    amp;elqid: "RSTesting123"
}
```

Which is not what I expected.
How can I get it to **not** use the `&amp;` and read it correctly?

Comment: What's the difference between second and thrid ? I don't see any

Comment: feck, the third uses `&amp;`

Comment: @r3plica what is your use case for the third one? I guess simply from an HTTP param point of you this is correct &amp;elqid - after the & follows the param name.

Comment: It's an external redirect; they are sending traffic to our site. My boss claims they have always used `&amp;` and it was working. Now it doesn't. I have updated my code to do this `var elq = params['elqid'] || params['amp;elqid'];` but I don't like it :(

Answer (score 0):

Following your comments, you wrote

```
http://localhost:4200/steps/one?cid=em-elq-33781&amp;elqid=RStesting123
```

It won't work because `&amp;` is called an [HTML Entity](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_symbols.asp), and it's read only in HTML, not in the URL.